# Who Wants to Present on StackExchange at Dreamforce 2016?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Every year since 2012I've done a Dreamforce session on the StackExchange, usually they're campfire kind of things but a couple have been bigger.

This year I think it'd be great to have a SFSE presentation done by users of the site, in the past I've always done it from the position of proposer/moderator, and I've talked with Pat a few times and Matt Bingham last year.

So who wants to take up the torch?

## 3 Edit: Replies, So 3 Speakers?

1. [Gaurav](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10881/gaurav-kheterpal)
2. [Chris](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3277/chris-duncombe)
3. [Mohith](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/645/mohith-shrivastava)

I reckon you guys should go for it!

Comment: the talk with Matt was 2014, 2015 was with me :p  - I'm still up for talking on this again too.

Comment: Gah! Yeah I got 2014 and 2015 backwards. Sorry buddy :)

Man... every year is a blur and they're all blurring together!

Comment: Don't forget to record the sessions or maybe use Periscope for the broadcast. It would be great to be able to take a look at you guys.

Comment: @SergeyUtko - The sessions are recorded depending on where they are hosted (Community Theatre/ Developer Zone/ Admin Zone/ any other zone). For your reference, here's a SFSE session from an earlier edition of Dreamforce - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYcklcNLL-Q

Comment: Based on the edit from @LaceySnr - I'm hoping we can at least start work on the session proposal - Mohith Chris (and Samuel) - I'll get in touch with you!

Comment: Thanks @gaurav.Looking forward to work with you

Comment: The results for this (and other) session proposal comes out later tonight. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Unfortunately, both session proposals (group proposal-me, Chris, Samuel, Mohith & Daniel's) related to StackExchange were rejected. We're seeing the after effects of Pat leaving Salesforce :(

Answer (score 15):

I'd love to take this up. I've always presented at the conference on hardcore mobile topics so this will be a welcome change :)

As in earlier years, we should have a couple of speakers to co-present this. I'll be glad to do this as a joint session with whoever wants to join.

Comment: Depending on what we want to present, I'd be happy to be involved as well.

Comment: It's mainly to talk about how SFSE has evolved over the years and how it helps out folks in the community - I've attended the session for last couple of years. Once (hoping) we've Matt's approval, we can work together on the proposal - perphaps with his guidance. Samuel, would you like to join & complete the 'SFSE DF16 Trio'? :)

Comment: Definitely, but possibly it's still early to already limit this to a trio ?

Comment: Not sure if this is all settled yet but if you need one more, I'd love to participate as well.

Answer (score 12):

I am also very interested in presenting the value stackexchange adds to entire salesforce community ecosystem .I often think myself as an example how much I was benefited from this site in terms of career growth ,knowledge and this will be my first dreamforce as well .

Comment: I feel much the same. Ditto on it being my first dreamforce too.

Comment: Do you guys know if there will be a SFSE breakfast again? I would echo Mohith about the impact this community has had on my growth and I would love to thank you both (@crmprodev) and others in person.

Comment: Hi Nick .Not sure if we will have breakfast or not but lets get in touch via twitter during dreamforce and say hello to each other :)

Answer (score 11):

I mentioned it in a comment, but I think 2 or 3 people co-presenting would be great and I'd be happy to be part of that group.  I'm game for what everyone thinks is best.

Answer (score 6):

What sort of content were you thinking of? Would it be an introduction to the site and how to best to contribute to it? What makes a good question/answer, etc...

I was thinking of submitting a SFSE talk with a different focus.
I'd go back through the questions asked and answered from the previous year (or so) looking for anything that really stood out from a technical perspective. Sort of a highlights reel.

We could go through the question and answer looking at how it worked and why the answer was interesting. There would plenty of opportunities to fire up an org and run through demos. So less focused on SFSE per se, and more on the content of the answers and what made them interesting. If fact, it could also source content from other forums and blogs. I'd need to figure out how to attribute each part to the person(s) who developed the content and probably check with the author first, especially with blog posts.

Would be happy to have a co-presenter.

Comment: Love the idea of this one — there's a heap of amazing answers on here that deep dive into technical topics.

Comment: I used this approach at DF'14 in a session called 'Find Your Feet on Force.com' where we picked some questions from Discussion Boards, Stack Exchange, Community etc. and walked through the solutions implementing them real time with a hands-on demo - it worked quiet well. I'm not sure if we want to have multiple sessions or have all interested present a single session? Thoughts?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal I was wondering if both sessions could co-exist as well. I wasn't sure of the content of the proposed SFSE talk. I assumed it is more of an introduction and how to get the most out of the site. I was thinking of doing a more technical talk with specific worked examples. I'll have to try and find a recording of your talk, as it sounds similar to what I'd like to try.

Comment: This would be awesome to hear about if you do it! Please post a new Meta discussion with links if/when it happens. :)